# Tensorflow2.0: How to convert a sparse tensor with rank(st_input) greater than 2 to RaggedTensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I am reading a text file through Data API and converting the text into TFRecords. When I am reading the records line by line, I am getting a sparse matrix of rank 2 which is easily being transformed into a RaggedTensor by `tf.RaggedTensor.from_sparse`. However, when I am reading the records in batch of size 10, resulting sparse tensor is of rank 3. In the documentation, it is written that `tf.RaggedTensor.from_sparse` works only with sparse tensors of rank 2. Is there a way to create RaggedTensors from a sparse tensor of rank 3? I tried `tf.sparse.reshape` and tried removing the axis=1. This was successful as I was able to print the output. But this seems a little hackish way to do and I am looking for something more tensorflow-ish. An example to reproduce my case is as follows:-

1. When reading tfrecords line by line-

   `indices = array([[ 0,  0],
          [ 0,  1],
          [ 0,  2],
          [ 0,  3],
          [ 0,  4],
          [ 0,  5],
          [ 0,  6],
          [ 0,  7],
          [ 0,  8],
          [ 0,  9],
          [ 0, 10]], dtype=int64)`
   `values = array([b'What', b'interesting', b'fact', b'about', b'India', b'can',
          b'you', b'add', b'to', b'my', b'knowledge?'], dtype=object)`
   `dense_shape=array([ 1, 11], dtype=int64)`
   `tf.RaggedTensor.from_sparse(tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices,values=values,dense_shape=dense_shape))`

gives

```
`<tf.RaggedTensor [[b'What', b'interesting', b'fact', b'about', b'India', b'can', b'you', b'add', b'to', b'my', b'knowledge?']]>`
```

2. When reading a batch of size 1 (actual batch size was 10 but that would become way too cumbersome):

```
`indices=array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  6],
       [ 0,  0,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  9],
       [ 0,  0, 10]], dtype=int64)`<br/>
`values=array([b'What', b'interesting', b'fact', b'about', b'India', b'can',
       b'you', b'add', b'to', b'my', b'knowledge?'], dtype=object)`<br/>
`dense_shape=array([ 1,  1, 11], dtype=int64)`<br/><br/>
`tf.RaggedTensor.from_sparse(tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices,values=values,dense_shape=dense_shape))`
```

gives an error message

```
`ValueError: rank(st_input) must be 2`
```

However, using the statement
`tf.sparse.reshape(tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices,values=values,dense_shape=dense_shape),shape=[1,11])` 
resolves this issue.

Apologies for the sloppy editing.